# How to create LambdaEdge with CloudFront trigger via AWS SAM?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sam, aws-lambda-edge

I am wondering if it's possible to create Lambda@Edge with CloudFront trigger using AWS SAM or SDK?

I have experience in creating Lambda with AWS EventBridge trigger via AWS SAM template.yml.

Below is the diagram that I made usig AWS Console. Would like to create same stack using AWS SAM or SDK

[Stack diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gygT.png)

I tried to implement the CloudFront trigger using the source code below but it only created the CloudFront distribution, not Lambda@Edge with CloudFront trigger

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Sample SAM configuration for Lambda@Edge to facilitate deployments and further updates

Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - staging
      - production
    Default: staging
    Description: Stage that can be added to resource names

Mappings:
  AliasMap:
    staging:
      Alias: "staging-app.achrafsouk.com"
    production:
      Alias: "app.achrafsouk.com"

Resources:
    CFDistribution:
        Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
        Properties:
          DistributionConfig:
            Enabled: 'true'
            Comment: !Sub '${Stage} - CI/CD for Lambda@Edge'
            Aliases:
              - !FindInMap [AliasMap, !Ref Stage, Alias]
            Origins:
              -
                Id: MyOrigin
                DomainName: aws.amazon.com
                CustomOriginConfig:
                  HTTPPort: 80
                  OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
            DefaultCacheBehavior:
              TargetOriginId: MyOrigin
              LambdaFunctionAssociations:
                - 
                  EventType: origin-request
                  LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version
              ForwardedValues:
                QueryString: 'false'
                Headers:
                  - Origin
                Cookies:
                  Forward: none
              ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all

    LambdaEdgeFunctionSample:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          CodeUri: 
          Role: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeFunctionRole.Arn
          Runtime: nodejs6.10
          Handler: index.handler
          Timeout: 5
          AutoPublishAlias: live 

    LambdaEdgeFunctionRole:
      Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      Properties:
          Path: "/"
          ManagedPolicyArns:
              - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Sid: "AllowLambdaServiceToAssumeRole"
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - "sts:AssumeRole"
                Principal:
                  Service: 
                    - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    - "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"

Outputs:
    LambdaEdgeFunctionSampleVersion: 
      Description: Lambda@Edge Sample Function ARN with Version
      Value: !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version

    CFDistribution: 
      Description: Cloudfront Distribution Domain Name
      Value: !GetAtt CFDistribution.DomainName
```

Comment: I thought that the trigger was not being created because it was not showing up in Lambda. But it turned out that the trigger was actually there. You can verify this by going into your CloudFront distribution, go to monitoring, then Lambda@Edge tab and you should see your associated Lambda function there.